# В чём проблема с записью в файл устройства?

Tags: linux, kernel

Пытаюсь реализовать работу с файлом устройства ("обрабатываемом" своим модулем).

Имеется структура вида :

```
typedef struct {
  int mode;
  int state;
} DevInfo;
DevInfo info;
```

Обработчик записи имеет вид :

```
void apply_mode(void)
{
    void* pointer = align_to_pointer(info.align);
    if(pointer != NULL) {
        printk("drivername writing new state %d at %p (based on align %d)\n", info.state, pointer, info.align);
        ...
    }
}
ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    ssize_t written = 0;
    const char* tmp = buff + len - 1;
    printk("device_write(%p,%p,%d,%p)\n", filp, buff, (int)len, off);
    written = sizeof (FanInfo);
    copy_from_user (&info, tmp, written);
    apply_mode ();
    return written;
}
```

Т.е. в выводе dmesg-а я должен увидеть что-то вида :

```
drivername writing new state $info.state at $adress (based on align $info.align)
```

Вызываю запись следующей программой :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    printf("Starting\n");
    if(argc >= 3) {
        printf("opening\n");
        int f = open("/dev/devicename", O_RDWR);
        if (f < 0) {
            printf("Can't open /dev/devicename\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("parsing\n");
        DevInfo info;
        info.align = atoi(argv[1]);
        info.state = atoi(argv[2]);
        printf("align %d, state %d\n", info.align, info.state);
        printf("writing\n");
        write(f, &info, sizeof(FanInfo));
        printf("closing\n");
        close(f);
    } else {
        printf("Too smaill argument count. Need 'main alignNumber speedNumber'\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке запуска :

```
# sudo test 2 4
Starting
opening
parsing
align 2, state 4
writing
```

Но в вывод dmesg вижу :

```
[160150.909063]       
device_write(ffff880189bc0c00,00007ffd420eda10,8,ffff8801d13bff50)
[160150.909069] drivername writing new state 0 at 000000001f6bceaf (based on align 0)
```

Т.е. после выполнения `copy_from_user (&info, tmp, written);` info занулён.
Как найти источник ошибки?

upd. похоже, я ошибся в подсчёте адреса :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка была в обработчике. Верный вариант

```
ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    ssize_t written = 0;
    const char* tmp = buff;
    printk("device_write(%p,%p,%d,%p)\n", filp, buff, (int)len, off);
    written = sizeof (FanInfo);
    copy_from_user (&info, tmp, written);
    apply_mode ();
    return written;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую придерживаться классического стиля

```
ssize_t mydev_write ( struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *off )
{
int len;

/*проверим режим доступа*/
  switch( file->f_flags & O_ACCMODE )
  {
    case O_WRONLY:
    case O_RDWR:
        break;
    case O_RDONLY:
          return(-EPERM);
    default:
          return(-EINVAL);
  }
len = sizeof (FanInfo);
if( *off >= len ) return(-ENOSPC);
/* Возможно тут уместней будет следующий код */
//if( size != len ) return(-EINVAL);

if( *off + size > len ) size = len - *off;
if( copy_from_user (&info, buf, size) )
   {
      return(-EFAULT);
   }
*off += size;

return(size);
}
```